# Como criar uma função com matriz e depois usa-la na int main substituindo valores de outra matriz?

Tags: c

Eu estou com duvida em como criar uma função onde usará os valores de uma matriz da int main, e depois como fazer para substituir os valores obtidos na matriz da função para a matriz do int main?

eu estava criando a função assim:

```
int JogadaComp2 (int tabuleiro[3][3])

 {

 if ( tabuleiro [2][2] = 0) { tabuleiro[2][2] = 1;return 0;} 

 if ( tabuleiro [1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro [1][2] == 2 && tabuleiro [1][3] == 
0) { tabuleiro[1][3] = 1;return 0;}

if ( tabuleiro [1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro [2][1] == 2 && tabuleiro [3][1] == 
0) { tabuleiro[3][1] = 1;return 0;}

return tabuleiro[3][3];

}
```

e para substituir os valores na matriz da int main:

```
int main (){

int tabuleiro[3][3];

tabuleiro[3][3] = JogadaComp2(tabuleiro[3][3]);

for(l=0;l<3;l++)
{
    for(c=0;c<3;c++)
    {   
    printf("%d", tabuleiro[l][c];
 }
 printf("\n";
}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se apenas pretende que a função altere valores na matriz `tabuleiro` não precisa de ter um tipo de retorno e pode deixar simplesmente como `void`. Só por si também já simplifica uma vez que deixa de precisar dos retornos:

```
void JogadaComp2 (int tabuleiro[3][3]) {

    if (tabuleiro[2][2] = 0) {
        tabuleiro[2][2] = 1;
    }

    if (tabuleiro [1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro [1][2] == 2 && tabuleiro [1][3] == 0) {
        tabuleiro[1][3] = 1;
    }

    if (tabuleiro [1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro [2][1] == 2 && tabuleiro [3][1] == 0) {
        tabuleiro[3][1] = 1;
    }
}
```

No main passa a ter que chamar esta função sem capturar o seu retorno:

```
JogadaComp2(tabuleiro);
```

Repare que quando passa uma matriz como parâmetro para uma função, não são especificados os indices, caso contrario estaria a passar um valor especifico ao invés da matriz toda.

Aproveito para dizer que também tinha alguns erros de escrita no seu código do main:

```
for(l=0;l<3;l++)
{// ^---- l não foi declarado
    for(c=0;c<3;c++)
    {// ^---- c também não foi declarado
    printf("%d", tabuleiro[l][c];
    //  ------------------------^ falta o ) de fecho
 }
 printf("\n";
 -----------^ falta aqui também o ) de fecho
}
```

Comment: Os erros de escrita são devido a eu ter resumido o código para tirar minha duvida, eu só resumi a parte que eu não estava conseguindo fazer. Mas de qualquer modo obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @RenanMela De nada. Fez bem em resumir, o objetivo é sempre ter o minimo necessário só para o problema em questão. Eu optei por assinalar na mesma porque fiquei na duvida se tinha de facto os erros ou não, e se fosse, também já sabia o que corrigir.